# merge two lists of dictionaries without ids in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I have two lists of dicts like this :

```
list1 =[{doc:1,pos_ini:5,pos_fin:10},{doc:1,pos_ini:7,pos_fin:12},{doc:2,pos_ini:5,pos_fin:10},**{doc:7,pos_ini:5,pos_fin:10}**]

list2 =
[{doc:1,pos_ini:5,pos_fin:10},**{doc:1,pos_ini:6,pos_fin:7}**,{doc:1,pos_ini:7,pos_fin:12},{doc:2,pos_ini:5,pos_fin:10},**{doc:2,pos_ini:25,pos_fin:30}**]
```

`list2` has two elements that `list1` does not have and `list1` has one element that `list2` does not have.

I need a `list_result` with all the elements merged :

```
list_result =[{doc:1,pos_ini:5,pos_fin:10},**{doc:1,pos_ini:6,pos_fin:7}**,{doc:1,pos_ini:7,pos_fin:12},{doc:2,pos_ini:5,pos_fin:10},
**{doc:2,pos_ini:25,pos_fin:30}**,**{doc:7,pos_ini:5,pos_fin:10}**]
```

Whats the best way to do that in Python ? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`frozenset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) to hash each dictionaries `items()` to a dictionary, then simply take the assigned values:

```
list({frozenset(x.items()): x for x in list1 + list2}.values())
```

Or using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) applied to a set comprehension:

```
list(map(dict, {frozenset(x.items()) for x in list1 + list2}))
```

Or even using just a list comprehension:

```
[dict(d) for d in {frozenset(x.items()) for x in list1 + list2}]
```

Which will give an *unordered* result:

```
[{'doc': 1, 'pos_fin': 10, 'pos_ini': 5},
 {'doc': 1, 'pos_fin': 12, 'pos_ini': 7},
 {'doc': 2, 'pos_fin': 10, 'pos_ini': 5},
 {'doc': 7, 'pos_fin': 10, 'pos_ini': 5},
 {'doc': 1, 'pos_fin': 7, 'pos_ini': 6},
 {'doc': 2, 'pos_fin': 30, 'pos_ini': 25}]
```

**Note:** If *order* is needed, you can use a [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead here:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

list(OrderedDict((frozenset(x.items()), x) for x in list1 + list2).values())
```

Which gives this *ordered* result:

```
[{'doc': 1, 'pos_fin': 10, 'pos_ini': 5},
 {'doc': 1, 'pos_fin': 12, 'pos_ini': 7},
 {'doc': 2, 'pos_fin': 10, 'pos_ini': 5},
 {'doc': 7, 'pos_fin': 10, 'pos_ini': 5},
 {'doc': 1, 'pos_fin': 7, 'pos_ini': 6},
 {'doc': 2, 'pos_fin': 30, 'pos_ini': 25}]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python there is the builtin `set` collection that is perfect for this. The problem is that sets need `hashable` elements so you must convert the dict to a set of tuples:

```
[dict(items) for items in set(tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in (list1 + list2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a set out of these values, instead of the dictionaries it would require to be converted into a hashable object like tuple:

```
unique_list = set(tuple(dictionary.items())) for dictionary in list1 + list2)
```

and then can be converted back to dictionaries and list format again:

```
l = []
for item in unique_list:
    l.append(dict(item))
```

Something like above should work.

Comment: In 3.6.1: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_items'`